# What is required to serve as an adapter with setAdapter()?

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-adapter, android-gridlayout, android-adapterview

AdapterView in question is **GridView**. I'm wondering what is exactly meant by "The setAdapter() method then sets a custom adapter (ImageAdapter) as the source for all items to be displayed in the grid." in this [android official guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html#example). Is it the **getView()** method?

My objective, is to create a gridview that gets inputs from a **SD card director**y, and not the resource folder. So instead of working with resources' ID's, i will work with absolute paths.

I am trying to set something like:

```
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);        
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, mImgFilenames));
```

With the image adapter being:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private List<String> mPaths;

// Store the list of image IDs
public ImageAdapter(Context c, List<String> paths) {
    mContext = c;
    this.mPaths = paths;
}

// Return the number of items in the Adapter
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mPaths.size();
}

// Return the data item at position
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mPaths.get(position);
}

// Will get called to provide the ID that
// is passed to OnItemClickListener.onItemClick()
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// Return an ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    if (imageView == null) {
     //typical code for new view
    }

    //load the image    
    Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile((String) getItem(position));
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
    return imageView;
}
```

}

So I am not talking about what are the mandatory methods to implement, but rather what is required of the adapter's infrastructure to serve as one. Speaking of which though, i have no idea what **getItemId** should return.

Comment: Since your model data is a `List`, why not use `ArrayAdapter`? That would be much simpler.

Comment: In the ImageAdapter? Doesn't the field there (mPaths) should be the actual database like array or list or something, and not an adapter?

Comment: No, I mean that your `ImageAdapter` should extend `ArrayAdapter`, not `BaseAdapter`. Then, you only really have to worry about `getView()` and nothing else.

Comment: Great! Will change it! And then override the constructor to load all the files from absolutes paths? If so, or if not, how to add the paths manually to the actual array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ImageAdapter` should extend `ArrayAdapter`, not `BaseAdapter`. Then, you only really have to worry about `getView()` and nothing else.

> And then override the constructor to load all the files from absolutes paths?

Please load the images asynchronously, using a library like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). Do **not** do disk I/O on the main application thread. You can do that in `getView()` itself, as the images are needed.

> how to add the paths manually to the actual array?

You already have an array of paths. It's called `paths` (as the constructor parameter to your current `ImageAdapter`) and `mPaths` (as the data member of your current `ImageAdapter`).

Comment: I know this is the way to go. But what to do with that TextView requirement in every constructor?

Comment: @PIXP: There are constructors that do not take the `TextView` ID. Not supplying the `TextView` ID means is that you cannot chain to `super.getView()`, but otherwise it should be fine.

Comment: With ArrayAdapter, it seems all constructors do require that in some way: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Comment: @PIXP: No, only half do. All take a layout resource ID, because usually a row/cell/whatever is more complex than a plain `ImageView`. You should be able to just pass `0` there.